# Cloudstack NFS Primary Storage showing 49.22 GB

Tags: nfs, centos6, libvirt, apache-cloudstack

How do I increase the amount of Primary Storage available in CloudStack.

I followed the Quickstart guide for cloudstack4.2.  I added the /primary and /seconday nfs and have a management and agent cloudstack service.  All the primary folders are showing as 49.22 GB no matter what.  I'm running this in Centos 6.4 on dual core Xeon computers with one master and several hosts.  I have 1 TB hdds on all hosts and the master (which I would like to utilize fully).

How can I increase the size of the primary storage?

Comment: Haha, figured it out...  
The root partition was 50GB hence the NFS was 50GB.  
So all i had to do is simply add a nfs location at /home/primary and /home/secondary because the /home partition was 800GB.  
Really dumb of me in hindsight.

Comment: You should post this comment as an answer to the question :)